# Unable to start ComponentInfo and Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is the error I am getting. I didn't make any changes in the following files so I'm unsure what is causing this issue.

The error is :
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apple.applen.assignment2/apple.applen.assignment2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in apple.applen.assignment2:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #18 in apple.applen.assignment2:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment

Complete error

```
2022-02-10 16:00:29.662 18187-18187/apple.applen.assignment2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: apple.applen.assignment2, PID: 18187
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{apple.applen.assignment2/apple.applen.assignment2_take2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in apple.applen.assignment2:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #18 in apple.applen.assignment2:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23 in apple.applen.assignment2:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #18 in apple.applen.assignment2:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18 in apple.applen.assignment2:layout/content_main: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class apple.applen.assignment2_take2.input.InputViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:188)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:238)
        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:112)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:169)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:139)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:44)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:31)
        at apple.applenn.assignment2_take2.input.InputFragment.getViewModel(InputFragment.kt:19)
        at apple.applen.assignment2_take2.input.InputFragment.onViewCreated(InputFragment.kt:52)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3019)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:551)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1374)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2841)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchViewCreated(FragmentManager.java:2777)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performViewCreated(Fragment.java:3020)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.ensureInflatedView(FragmentStateManager.java:394)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:260)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:142)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:295)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:274)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.tryCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:1067)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:995)
2022-02-10 16:00:29.662 18187-18187/apple.applen.assignment2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:1261)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1117)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at apple.applen.assignment2_take2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:44)
        at apple.applen.assignment2_take2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:38)
        at apple.applen.assignment2_take2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<apple.applen.assignment2_take2.input.InputViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:186)
            ... 50 more
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Assignment2_Take2.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.Assignment2_Take2.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

InputViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class InputViewModel @Inject constructor(
    public val repository: GameRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    val _saved = MutableLiveData<Event<String>>()
    val saved: LiveData<Event<String>> = _saved

    fun save(game : Game){
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
            val id = repository.insert(game)
            _saved.postValue(Event(id))
        }
    }
}
```

InputFragment

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class InputFragment : Fragment() {
    private val viewModel: InputViewModel by viewModels()
    private var _binding: FragmentInputBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentInputBinding
        get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentInputBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)



        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.playButton.setOnClickListener { save() }

        // show output when the data is saved in the database
        viewModel.saved.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObserver{ id ->
            showOutput(id)
        })

    }



    private fun save(){
        //Get User Selection
        val userChoice : GameChoices = when (binding.choiceGroup.checkedRadioButtonId){
            R.id.rock_button -> GameChoices.Rock
            R.id.paper_button -> GameChoices.Paper
            R.id.scissor_button -> GameChoices.Scissor
            else -> GameChoices.Rock
        }

        //Generate computer choice
        val randomChoice = (0..2).random()
        val computerChoice = when (randomChoice){
            0 -> GameChoices.Rock
            1 -> GameChoices.Paper
            2 -> GameChoices.Scissor
            else -> "Undefined"
        }

        //Calculate winner
        var calculateWinner = ""
        calculateWinner = if(
            userChoice == GameChoices.Rock && computerChoice == GameChoices.Scissor ||
            userChoice == GameChoices.Paper && computerChoice == GameChoices.Rock ||
            userChoice == GameChoices.Scissor && computerChoice == GameChoices.Paper
        ){
            "Winner is User"
        } else if(userChoice == computerChoice){
            "No winner"
        }else{
            "Winner is Computer"
        }

        val winner = calculateWinner
        viewModel.save(Game(null, computerChoice as GameChoices, userChoice, winner ))

    }

    private fun showOutput(gameId: String) {
        findNavController().navigate(
            InputFragmentDirections.actionInputFragmentToOutputFragment(gameId)
        )
    }


    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
```

Comment: Added the full error

Comment: My bad. Added the rest

Comment: `InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<apple.applen.assignment2_take2.input.InputViewModel> has no zero argument constructor` – That's the root problem, there. I'm assuming the Hilt setup should be handling that somehow, but I'm not that familiar with it, unfortunately.